# three.js how to cache (store localy) 3d models and textures?

Tags: javascript, php, three.js

Im making a game with three.js and game levels are different pages. So when you go from one level to another, browser reloads page. I want to somehow store models locally so that they are not downloaded again. Can I store 3d model in cookie or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider [ApplicationCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

Comment: that sounds good. so if collection of levels share one group of models, and another collection of levels share another group of models, i can differ that with different manifest files? For example, I don't want to cache model that appears only on last level right away.