# Cache scene in Three.js

Tags: caching, three.js

PIXI.js has `Container#cacheAsBitmap` which causes the container to "render" itself to an image, save that, render the image instead of its children and when a child is added or removed or updated, the cache is updated.

What's the alternative for Three.js (but instead of an image it would be a mesh)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be understanding your question properly, but your reply to Sabee's answer was helpful.  It sounds like you're looking to either merge multiple geometries into a single mesh or implement a form of model instancing, with the goal of reducing draw calls.

There is more than one way to accomplish this, depending on your requirements.  You can merge multiple geometries into a single geometry object, and provide either one material or an array of materials (where each index corresponds to one of the merged geometries).  You can also use GPU-accelerated instancing to achieve a similar effect with only a single copy of the geometry.

I'll refer to Dusan Bosnjak's excellent Medium series on instancing, which starts here: https://medium.com/@pailhead011/instancing-with-three-js-36b4b62bc127

As well, here are the three.js examples regarding instancing: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instanc#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Pixi.js is a 2D javascript library, using WebGL to render the images(frames) into html5 canvas. Three.js allows the creation of Graphical Processing Unit (GPU)-accelerated 3D animations using WebGL. 
The browser cannot store rendered 3D frames, this work allows the GPU Accelerated Render Cache, which depends on what hardware's they run. [Helpful post](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome) understanding what's going on behind the scenes.

But you can cahce your assets in browser like images, json objects of 3D models and etc. 
In Three.js [Cache class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/Cache) is a global object, used by assets loaders (TextureLoader, ImageLoader, AudioLoader ...), by default is disabled (`false`). To enable it you can set `THREE.Cache.enabled = true ;`

I think by default the browser should cache the textures for performance reasons, but if you want to be sure simply enable the cache by force code it in Three.js. Also the creator of Three.js answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22702955/9016196).

Comment: Hi, that's not what I'm asking. PIXI can cache to an image but Three could combine multiple meshes into one and upload that to the GPU for a single render call- this is exactly what's done in voxel meshing for instance except that there you remove some faces too and do other magic.

Comment: I think unfortunately there is not possible in Three.js now, you have to implement it yourself :(